# Ruby Executing Bash Commands on Linux

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a ruby script to change my wireless mac address quickly by using "macchanger" tool.I have all the root permission to change it. And I try this:

```
  `ifconfig #{@wifi_device.getName()} down`
  output= `macchanger -m AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF #{@wifi_device.getName()}`
  `ifconfig #{@wifi_device.getName()} up`
```

It usually works well , however when there is a problem , for example I enter an invalid mac address, and the bash prints any error , I can not catch it from Ruby.It prints only success messages , not errors. When I tried an invalid mac ,
My question if there is any suggestion to get rid of executing bash commands and read the output properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell needs to know where to send stderr. `2>&1` is a great way to do this it redirects 2(stderr) to 1(stdout) which is what "output" is capturing.

```
 output= `macchanger -m AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF #{@wifi_device.getName()} 2>&1`
```

The Advanced Bash Scripting Guide has a great chapter on [I/O Redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

Comment: I am glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

When you use [this](https://github.com/acrogenesis/macchanger) macchanger, then you don't need to call a shell command. You can put macchanger into your current folder and `require_relative './macchanger'` . After this you can use the class `MacChanger`

Comment: Thank you for suggestion , I am gonna use it

Comment: Although this does not answer your question directly. This is a better programmatic solution to your application. Eliminating the need to do error redirect/checking by hand and offloading that onto the greater community.